# joining two tables and avoid duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am stuck with below logic in sql server.

Table 1:

```
ID  Requestid  
1    0001       
2    0004       
3   0004        
1   0005
```

Table 2

```
parentID  Requestid  Age
1         0001       29
2         0004       30
3         0004        34
1         0005        27
```

query:

```
select * from table1 t1
join table t2
on t2.parentid =t1.id
```

When I join these tables, I am getting below result

```
ID       requestid         age
1         0001             29
1         0005             29
2         0004             30
3         0004             34
1         0001             27
1         0005             27
```

I want below result:

```
ID       requestid         age
1         0001             29
1         0005             27
2         0004             30
3         0004             34
```

I know it is simple and i am missing something.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ID, requestid, age from table1 t1
inner join table t2
on t2.parentid =t1.id AND t2.requestId = t1.requestId
ORDER BY ID
```

OR

```
select ID, requestid, age from table1 t1,table t2    
where t2.parentid =t1.id AND t2.requestId = t1.requestId
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: perfect! i missed order by ID and joined on two other columns.